# Delete "Post Published. View Post" for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, notifications

I'm working on a plugin with a custom post type called "important_dates"

I want to delete the Wordpress admin notification when a new custom post is created.

Here is my code - it deletes the notifications for all post types. How do I make it work for only my "important_dates" custom post type?

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'post_published' );

function post_published( $messages )
{
    unset($messages['posts'][6]);
    return $messages;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like above should work:

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'post_published' );

function post_published( $messages )
{
   if ( 'important_dates' === get_post_type() ){
       unset($messages['posts'][6]);
   }
   return $messages;
}
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full code

```
function post_published( $messages )
{
  if ( 'important_dates' === get_post_type() ){
    unset($messages['posts'][6]);
  } else {
    return $messages;
}
}
```

Comment: thank you I've corrected my code below because in my first case like in yours, sometines $messages isn't returned. Now it is.